# Update "replaced" Omnifocus in Applications

Tags: mac, installation, omnifocus

I had Omnifocus 3 and I installed Omnifocus 4. When it had me drag the app into Applications, it asked me if I wanted to keep one or both the old or new apps. I chose to "replace" the old app. Now all my tasks are gone. Is there a way to restore my tasks?

I have sync turned off due to work requirements.

Comment: Hope you have a backup! Also this might be best asked of Omni tech support. I hear they are excellent and quite responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from their support was that the DB is stored apart from the app. So I just had to reinstall Omnifocus 3 in a separate Applications sub folder and my data was back. Then I had to do a data export from 3 and import into 4 to transfer the data to the new app version.